# data base division

Tags: sql, oracle

Tables :

`PILOTE(NOPIL, PLNOM, ADR)`

`AVION(NOAV, NOMAV, CAPAC, LOC)`

`VOL(NOVOL, #NOPIL, #NOAV, VDEP, VARR, HDEP, HARR)`

Question : What are the numbers of the pilots (nopil) who drive at least all of the company's Airbuses?

Answer :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    nopil
FROM vol v, avion a
WHERE v.noav = a.noav
AND nomav = 'Airbus'
GROUP BY nopil
HAVING COUNT(distinct noav) = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM avion WHERE nomav = 'Airbus'
);
```

I can't understand the answer.

Comment: That answer looks a bit poor. Consider another SQL course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` is redundant and you can convert the legacy join syntax to a modern ANSI join syntax which gives you:

```sql
SELECT nopil                            -- 5 (numbers for the points below)
FROM   vol v                            -- 1
       INNER JOIN avion a               -- 1
       ON (v.noav = a.noav)             -- 1
WHERE  a.nomav = 'Airbus'               -- 2
GROUP BY nopil                          -- 3
HAVING COUNT(distinct noav)             -- 4
         = (SELECT COUNT(*)             -- 4
            FROM   avion                -- 4
            WHERE  nomav = 'Airbus')    -- 4
;
```

Which is saying:

1. Consider `JOIN`ing the `vol` and `avion` tables together using the foreign key relationship on the `noav` column.
2. Then consider only those rows `WHERE` the name/type of the aviation (`nomav`) equals `= 'Airbus'`.
3. Then `GROUP` the rows into sets for each number of the pilot (`nopil`)
4. Then further restrict it to only those pilot numbers `HAVING` a `COUNT` of `DISTINCT` (different) `noav` values within their set of rows equal to `=` the `COUNT` of the rows `*` `FROM` the `avion` table `WHERE` the name/type of the aviation (`nomav`) equals `= 'Airbus'`. So this last condition will eliminate any rows where the count for each `nopil` is less than the total number of Airbuses.
5. Then for each remaining grouped set of rows `SELECT` the number of the pilot (`nopil`) for that set.
6. Then you are left with only the "numbers of the pilots (`nopil`) who drive at least all of the company's Airbuses?"